# Flex: Dynamically drawn group, with mouse events

Tags: apache-flex, drawing

I have a Group on my View and i'm trying to fill it with some collor and add a mouse event, all dynamicaly.
the problem is, when i add the mouse event, the group simply turns invisible again. It still exists on the view and responds normally to mouse events, but i can't see it

here's a code example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="HomeView" creationComplete="onCreationComplete()" >
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

                public function onCreationComplete():void
                {
                    testeGroup.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
                    testeGroup.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, testeGroup.width, testeGroup.height);
                    testeGroup.graphics.endFill();

                    testeGroup.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function ():void{
                        trace("test");
                    });
                }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Group id="testeGroup" verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0" width="100" height="100" >

    </s:Group>

</s:View>
```

without the mouse event the group is visible, but it vanishes when i try to add it. i've tried with other events, like the ENTER_FRAME Event and it works normaly, but all the mouse events that i tried turn the Group invisible.

i've actually solved my problem using the opaqueBackground property, the Group don't vanish when i add the event this whay. But now i'm curious about the reason of this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sort of interesting, for whatever reason adding a listener makes a call to invalidateDisplayList, this means during the next enter frame updateDisplayList will be called, in the Group updateDisplayList it makes a call to graphics.clear(), it also calls drawBackground() which does a graphics.clear().  Basically drawing to an objects graphics from the outside like this tends to create these kinds of weird behaviors, I think it's best to extend the Group then do your drawing in updateDisplayList.

To be a bit more specific the addEventListener code in GroupBase sets a property hasMouseListeners and in the setter there it invalidates the display list, the list of events this will occur for is here:

```
        case MouseEvent.CLICK:
        case MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK:
        case MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN:
        case MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE:
        case MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER:
        case MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT:
        case MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT:
        case MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER:
        case MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP:
        case MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL:
        case TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN:
        case TouchEvent.TOUCH_END:
        case TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE:
        case TouchEvent.TOUCH_OUT:
        case TouchEvent.TOUCH_OVER:
        case TouchEvent.TOUCH_ROLL_OUT:
        case TouchEvent.TOUCH_ROLL_OVER:
        case TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP:
        case GestureEvent.GESTURE_TWO_FINGER_TAP:
        case PressAndTapGestureEvent.GESTURE_PRESS_AND_TAP:
        case TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_PAN:
        case TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ROTATE:
        case TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE:
        case TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ZOOM:
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use a Graphic as a child of the Group and modify the graphics of the Graphic instead of the graphics of the enclosing Group.

```
<s:Group
    id="doNotUseMyGraphicsBecauseItWillNotWork"
    >
    <s:Graphic
        id="useMyGraphicsInstead"
        />
</s:Group>
```